# When someone uses threats to compel someone else to do something, how do you describe it?

Tags: prepositions, articles, phrase-request

When someone uses threats to compel someone else to do something, how do you describe it?

Specifically, what preposition should I use, should I use an article in the expression ***under the threat of death/eviction etc.***? It sounds okay to me, I see nothing wrong with it, but Google News results [don't](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22under%20the%20threat%20of%22&newwindow=1&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ALeKk02D7IeIgV7BMxY65T1gItrjKQz9Ag:1589610400936&ei=oIe_XofWOI2Bk74P1d6h6Ac&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiHpp2a4LfpAhWNwMQBHVVvCH04FBDy0wMIWQ&biw=1536&bih=726&dpr=1.25) seem reassuring.

Comment: side note: you can also use *-threat* to make compound nouns like death-threat.

Comment: Are you interested in alternate ways of saying that, or do you just want to know about the preposition concerning the words "threat" or "death"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legal term is "extortion", or the related verb "extort"

If the threat is to reveal a secret, the term is blackmail.

> The gangster extorted $1000 by threatening to set fire to the property.
>
> Jim was blackmailed by an ex-employee, who threatened to reveal the company's history of tax evasion.

Both extortion and blackmail are crimes.

"Under the treat of death" is okay, but consider:

> He fled the country under the treat of death.
>
> He fled the country after receiving death-threats.